# The number of people that enter a drugstore problem (Probability)

Tags: probability

Q.
The number of people that enter a drugstore in a given hour is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda = 10$. Compute the conditional probability that at most 3 men entered the drugstore, given that $10$ women entered in that hour. What assumptions have you made?

I set $X$ to be the random variable of men entering a drugstore and $Y$ to be the random variable of women entering a drugstore, if I set the condition of the probability of the sex of the visitor to be equal, then why can I divide this group into $2$ Poisson groups?

What I am trying to say is, I know if $A$ and $B$ are Poisson variables of parameters $a$ and $b$, the $A+B$ is a Poisson variable of parameter $a+b$. But is it okay dividing Poisson variable into $2$ Poisson variables?

And are X and Y independent? If so, why?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

If $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ are *independent* Poisson-distributed random variables with parameters $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $ respectively, then $\ A+B\ $ is Poisson-distributed with parameter $\ a+b\ $. However, when  $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ are *not* independent, then $\ A+B\ $ is not necessarily Poisson-distributed, even if both $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ are.

I doubt if $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ really are independent in practice, but I'm reasonably sure you'd be expected to make that assumption (and, of course, explicitly state that you've made it) to answer the question.